# GWT setting the position of a SuggestBox

Tags: jquery, gwt

I am using a [SuggestBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html) in GWT to create a text box with a nice suggestion list like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();  
    oracle.add("Cat");
    oracle.add("Dog");
    oracle.add("Horse");
    oracle.add("Canary");
    SuggestBox box = new SuggestBox(oracle);
    RootPanel.get().add(box);
    }
}
```

The thing is that I would like the suggestion list to appear on TOP of the text box, instead of at the BOTTOM of it.

Is there any way of doing this?

If not, is there any alternative in GWT to the SuggestBox? (I successfully managed to configure jQuery's [autocompletion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) widget to show up on top of the text box, but integrating that with GWT seems to be neither elegant nor efficient...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is any built-in way to do that, but I think it could be done with a little bit of work. `SuggestBox` has a constructor that takes a `SuggestionDisplay` as parameter. So you could subclass `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` and override its `showSuggestions()` method to display the popup where you want.

Comment: +1 Note, that most of the code needed to calculate the correct position is already there: If the SuggestBox is near the bottom of the window, it's automatically shown on top. The code is in `PopupPanel.position()`. Since this method is private, it can't be overridden, but you can override `PopupPanel.showRelativeTo(final UIObject target)`, and just use a slightly adapted version of `position()`. Also override `DefaultSuggestionDisplay.createPopup()` to use your popup.

Comment: Thanks Chris!, you are right, the code is already there, I just need to modify it. Unfortunately, I can't override `PopupPanel.showRelativeTo(final UIObject target)` because it is a final method. I can't find any other suitable option, any ideas?

Comment: @Mike: I totally overlooked the final modifier. In that case, it's probably best to override `DefaultSuggestionDisplay.showSuggestions()`, as David already wrote. You can still re-use most of PopupPanel.position()'s code...